# Django models and Postgres privileges

Tags: postgresql, django-models

So I'm new at Django development and I haven't figured out how models and postgresql privileges work together.

I have a postgreql database with a schema called AUTH with all the models that Django auth creates(auth_user, auth_permission, etc). The user that I passed on DATABASES on settings.py is a user that has no SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, etc privileges on any table on that SCHEMA (I was making some tests) but when I create any user it gets written on auth_user table on SCHEMA AUTH.

So how does postgresql privileges and Django models are put together?

Thanks